# Why am I getting the error code System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'item')' When I try to launch my form?

Tags: c#, forms

This is my code:

```
namespace Televisie
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        bool BoolAanUit;

        void ZenderArray()
        {
            
            string[] Zenders = new string[100];
            Zenders[0] = "NPO1";
            Zenders[1] = "NPO2";
            Zenders[2] = "NPO3";

            LbZenders.Items.Clear();

            for(int i= 0; i < Zenders.Length; i++) 
            {
                LbZenders.Items.Add(Zenders[i]);
            }
        }

        void AanUit()
        {
            if (BoolAanUit)
            {
                tbStatus.Text = "Aan";
            }
            else
            {
                tbStatus.Text = "Uit";
            }
        }

        private void RbAan_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BoolAanUit = true;
            AanUit();
            ZenderArray();
        }

        private void tbStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void RbUit_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BoolAanUit = false;
            AanUit();
            LbZenders.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void LbZenders_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to launch my form, it gives this error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'item')'

I tried different things but they all came down to the same error, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like 97 of the 100 items in your array of strings are null, so they're being rejected for storage in whatever `LbZenders.Items` is.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add null items to the LbZenders.Items which results in:

> Blockquote System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'item')'

To solve this you can assign space values to all the empty elements of the Zenders list.

Hope that works.